# Searching and selecting strings from a file

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, grep, debian

I have a trouble in separating few exact 'fields' with strings and then putting them into .txt file. I need to extract 'nologin' users from /etc/passwd file and that is an easy step. I'm using this command:

```
grep -n 'nologin' /etc/passwd > file1.txt
```

cat command gives me for example:

```
2:daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
3:bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
4:sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

and it is saved to file1.txt

Now I have to extract from file1.txt a number (2, 3, 4), login (daemon, bin, sys) UID and shell. It should look like this

```
2:daemon:1:/usr/sbin/nologin
3:bin:2:/usr/sbin/nologin
4:sys:3:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

I also have to save that output to a *.txt file.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [cut](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command like this:

```
cut -d':' -f1 file1.txt > file2.txt
```

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

> -d, --delimiter=DELIM
>
> use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
>
> -f, --fields=LIST
>
> select only these fields; also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified

Comment: This resolves my issue! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use awk to get your specific fields
1- Go to your terminal and make sure you know your file path 
2- use awk commands where -F use to indicate the separator and $ use to indicate the field number

your file1.txt contains:

2:daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
3:bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
4:sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin

using awk command in your terminal with file1

```
awk -F '[:/]' '{print $1 " " $2 " " $4 " " " " $(NF-2) " " $(NF-1) " "      $NF}' file1.txt
```

make sure your file path is correct

```
$1 or $2 = the number of field or column
```

$NF  = last column
   $(NF-1) = the column before the last column 
   and so on 
   " " = mean space

your output will be:

2 daemon 1  usr sbin nologin
3 bin 2  usr sbin nologin
4 sys 3  usr sbin nologin

you can add the delimiter back in the awk command instead of space

for example,

```
awk -F '[:/]' '{print $1 ":" $2 ":" $4 ":/" $(NF-2) "/" $(NF-1) "/" $NF}' file1.txt
```

output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r5ph.png)

Thanks and Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '{print $1,$2,$4,$NF}' OFS=: file1.txt > newfile.txt

2:daemon:1:/usr/sbin/nologin
3:bin:2:/usr/sbin/nologin
4:sys:3:/usr/sbin/nologin
```